# MySQLd doesn't start after brew upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, homebrew

a few days back I let brew update all my formulars like always but this time mysqld doesn't start back up again.

This is the error message:

```
2016-03-22T13:58:22.515719Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade.
2016-03-22T13:58:22.515819Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

But since I cannot get the server started, I cannot get mysql_upgrade running:

```
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102 while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
```

So what can I do to get this working again? Would a `brew uninstall mysql` and reinstall help in any way?

Answer (score 31):

First, start your mysql without reading the user table:
`mysqld --skip-grant-tables`

Then run `mysql_upgrade` which should now run smoothly.

Next stop mysqld: `killall mysqld`.

Now you should be able to start up your mysql service normally again.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.4 LTS I needed to create folder /var/run/mysql manually first, otherwise it wouldn't start.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up renaming my database folder, run `mysql_install_db`, copy the new `mysql` database folder to my old mysql database folder and started it again. I'm sure this is hella dirty but well, it worked :)