# MySql57 Windows Service won't start

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I had installed MySQL 5.7 on my local machine and was connecting using host 127.0.0.1 and port 3306. After I restarted my machine I am unable to connect to the server. When I try to start the Windows service MySQL57 it does not start. The error message in the event viewer is Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade. When I try to run this MySQL_upgrade through command promt it gives the error:
Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost<10061> while connecting to the MySQL server.

When I do a netstat -an, I can't see the port 3306 as available or being used by any other process.

I have tried uninstalling and installing the Server component but I get the same error through the MySQL Installer wizard.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36156475/62576) help?

Comment: Appreciate the quick response Ken. That command works in Linux. I am running this on Windows. And that option isn't available in Windows.

Comment: Um... Renaming the folder and then reinstalling isn't applicable to Windows? Since when?

Comment: mysql_install_db this command doesn;'t work.