# mysql not start in CentOS 6.9 after upgrading 5.1 to 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have upgrade mysql 5.1 to mysql 5.7 in CentOS6.9 . BUt now when I try to start mysql , mysql not start 
[image: here show mysql 5.7]

Comment: There must be an upgrade log somewhere to get more information. It is very difficult to help you with this information only.

Comment: 2018-06-25T06:17:39.477118Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade.

Comment: Better to ask this question in our sister site [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or refer this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36156475/5180017)